# Want to redirect an article's link in web application URL to open the article in cocoa application

Tags: java, apache, redirect

I am using  a web application which will open different links as -->

https://app.com/view?article=Manual

I want to redirect these article links of the web application URL to open the article page in Cocoa application.

For example, on clicking the web application article link Say  https://app.com/view?article=Manual

This article should open the cocoa application with link as

Cocoaapp://article=Manual

I think redirect URL in apache can do that, but how will I retain the same article ID as here article=Manual can vary to different values like article=Instruct article=ABC etc.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the group capturing as below -

RewriteRule ^https://app.com/view?article=([a-z0-9]+)/$ Cocoaapp://article=$1